# generate sub scheme from specific model using railsroady

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml, database-schema, class-diagram

I use railsroady (rails roady) for a while now and I would like to know if it's possible to generate a subscheme using a starting model and it's related models and asociations?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the UML relation here?

Comment: @ThomasKilian my goal is to generate an UML class diagram and maybe rails roady use a syntax based on UML rules to do what I'm looking for, that' why I added uml as tag